# Css div wont go to the top or all the way to the sides

Tags: html, css

I have started a website with a redbackground and i want a little bit of white at the top.

i have this code:

CSS:

```
body {

background-color: #ff4d4d;
}
#header {
background-color: #ffffff;
height: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Fat Oblongs</title>
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Which produces:
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should make sure your `body` and `html` elements have no margin and padding:

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Sidenote: you *also* really should not use XHTML 1.0 Transitional as your doctype. If possible, simply use HTML5 <sub>(this has no influence over your borders, but still, don't use transitional doctypes unless you have a very good reason to do so)</sub>

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: @Narhem, I would not suggest using `*`. It would be better to use a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), or a simple selector like the one mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
body, html {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Browsers tend to have a few pixels of padding/margins around the window edges. The above CSS removes that all.

Answer (score 1):

you need to reset margin:padding of the body to zero

```
body {margin:0;padding:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79w9Y/